# Phonons from Born-Oppenheimer approximation vs plasma oscillations

Tags: condensed-matter, phonons, born-oppenheimer-approximation

I'm trying to connect to different pictures used when talking about phonon dispersion relations in metals. Both can be found in standard textbooks, for example Ashcroft & Mermin.

In the first, one starts with the Born Oppenheimer approximation, which says that ions move in an effective potential provided by the electronic eigenergies. This effective potential (take the electronic groundstate) can be expanded to second order around an equilibrium position which leads to harmonic lattice vibrations. The eigenmodes of these vibrations are the phonon modes. We get $3p$ different branches, where p is the number of atoms per unit cell, 3 of which are acoustic phonons, the rest are optical.

In the second picture one assumes a homogeneous gas of ions and shows that the charge density can oscillate at a plasma frequency. The electrons are taken into account by not using the bare Coulomb potential between ions but the screened potential. Using the dielectric function derived from Thomas-Fermi screening one obtains a single acoustic phonon branch (with $\omega(k) \propto k$ for small $k$). Using Linhard screening one also obtains Kohn anomalies in this phonon branch.

My questions are:

Where are the other phonon branches in the second approach?

Is screening not somehow taken into account automatically in the first approach, since the reaction of the electrons to the ion position should be contained in the effective potential? If so, why are there no Kohn anomalies in the first approach?

Comment: I am kind of lost, isn't the second approach for electrons in a metal? Do you have a chapter in the book?

Comment: @Mauricio see for example Chapter 26 of Solid state physics by Ashroft and Mermin

Comment: The 2nd approach is so incredibly rough, I am sure you will not be needing it for anything more than a back-of-the-envelope estimate. Just do the first approach.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent it seems to be needed for consistently treat metals.

Comment: That is definitely not the case. We treat metals using Born-Oppenheimer too. I think you are confusing the treatment of phonons with electrons. But yes, it is theoretically rather important to study the jellium model to get a sense of what electron liquid is doing, and in that sense we care about the 2nd approach.